# Google GWT custom themes

Tags: gwt

I'm looking for a good tutorial about creating a custom GWT themes. Could you propose me some url ?

Comment: P.S. Please skip www.google.com - I know this one :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a tutorial, but a online theme generator: http://gwt-theme-generator.appspot.com/. You can use it as a starting point. Not sure if it's up-to-date with the latest GWT version (2.4).

Answer (score 0):

Have you chance to look at default one? **http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/style.html**

Also I love this blog post
**https://blog.makk.es/gwt-uibinder-multiple-templates-one-owner-class.html** it gives me insight on how to have several templates for one controller.